# Multiple Image Pickers in one Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an onboarding flow for my app. I'm wanting to allow users to pick an avatar, display that avatar in an image view, and then select a background photo and display that in another image view. Currently, I have everything coded up, but for some reason when I present the picker controller, it defaults to controller for the avatar. I want the avatar button to only control the avatar button background image and the background button to only control the header image background image. Here's my code:

```
 @IBAction func getBackground(sender: AnyObject) {
    let backgroundPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    backgroundPickerController.delegate = self
    backgroundPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    backgroundPickerController.allowsEditing = true
    self.presentViewController(backgroundPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func selectAvatar(sender: AnyObject) {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
    self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    // set image for button
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.addAvatar.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)

    // Dismiss controller
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}

func backgroundPickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
  // set image for button
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.headerImage.image = image
     self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegate function `imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?)` also returns the `UIImagePickerController` that finished picking an image.

So you can use an `if` statement to check if the picker that finished is pickerOne or pickerTwo. Then you implement different behaviour according to the result of that.

Maybe set the pickers to `nil` after they have finished to clean up some memory.

```
class multiPickerVC : UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    var pickerOne : UIImagePickerController?
    var pickerTwo : UIImagePickerController?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //
    }


    @IBAction func getBackground(sender: AnyObject) {
        pickerTwo = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerTwo!.delegate = self
        pickerTwo!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        pickerTwo!.allowsEditing = true
        self.presentViewController(pickerTwo!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func selectAvatar(sender: AnyObject) {
        pickerOne = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerOne!.delegate = self
        pickerOne!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        pickerOne!.allowsEditing = true
        self.presentViewController(pickerOne!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        if picker == pickerOne {

            // set image for button
            let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
            self.addAvatar.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)

        } else if picker == pickerTwo {

            // set image for button
            let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

            self.headerImage.image = image
        }

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```